# Android Fragment and Adapter issue

Tags: java, android

I have made a sample chat layout which just adds the EditText input to a RecyclerView, but as you see in this picture after the fifth item it doesn't work the way it shoud (the numbers are the EditText outputs)[image]

Fragment class =>

```
Boolean me = true ;
Boolean seen = false ;

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

   if (view.getId() == R.id.send_button) {
        me = !me ;
        seen = !seen ;
        sendMessage();

    }



}
private void sendMessage(){


    String editTextString = editText.getText().toString() ;

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance() ;
    String time = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR) + ":" + calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) ;

    first_message.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    if (editTextString.equals("")){
        return;
    }
    E08Object object = new E08Object();
    object.setMessage(editText.getText().toString());
    object.setDate(time);
    object.setMe(me);
    object.setSeen(seen);


    list.add(object) ;
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    fragment_recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(list.size());
    editText.setText("");




}
```

Adapter class =>

```
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull VH holder, int position) {
    holder.textView.setText(list.get(position).getMessage());
    holder.timeTextVIew.setText(list.get(position).getDate());

        if (!list.get(position).getMe()) {
            holder.seenImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.fragmentParent.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(Application.getContext() , R.drawable.person_message_rounded));

        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check. You must reset value in else block inside bindViewHolder as the views are recycled.

```
if (!list.get(position).getMe()) {
  holder.seenImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  holder.fragmentParent.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(Application.getContext() , R.drawable.person_message_rounded));
} else {
  holder.seenImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  holder.fragmentParent.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(Application.getContext() , R.drawable.THE_DEFAULT_DRAWABLE));
}
```

This should help if this issue is due to recycling. Let me know if this helps. Also, better to attach the item layout and the recycler layout.